# Can I turn the error message "No visible @interface for 'FooClass' declares the selector 'bar'" back into a warning?

Tags: objective-c, llvm-clang

```
- (void)doIt
{
    [_foo bar];
    // produces compile time error: "No visible @interface for 'FooClass'
    // declares the selector 'bar'"
}
```

In the earlier days of Objective-C, when I called a method that the compiler doesn't know about, I would just get a warning. Then, something like a year ago, the compiler changed and such things are now an error. Does anybody know when this happened (`__weak` ?)

### What I did to solve the problem

There are a few methods that I know which can solve the problem, somehow. However, I hope there is an easier way.

#### A) declare an interface

```
@interface FooClass (MichaelHacksIt)
- (void) bar;
@end

// ...

- (void) doIt
{
    [_foo bar];
}
```

#### B) use `-performSelector:`

```
- (void)doIt
{
    [_foo performSelector:@selector(bar)];
}
```

#### C)

Because solution B sometimes produces an 'Undeclared selector' warning, and because we don't want Apple to know which methods we are calling, at all times, there is a third solution:

```
- (void)doIt
{
    SEL bar_sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"bar");
    [_foo performSelector:bar_sel];
}
```

#### D)

If the arguments to the method call are not just objects, we need to use `NSInvocation` instead. That's really ugly.

### What I would like to do

Is there maybe some compiler switch that disables the error? Under the hood, a message send is always just a call to `objc_msgSend()`, and linking to the method implementation is done at runtime. So, disabling the error should in principle be possible. What I would like to do is something similar to:

```
- (void)doIt
{
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang error disable objc_method_unknown_error
    [_foo bar];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

Is there such a compile time switch? Is there maybe a compiler flag that can be passed at the command line that produces this behaviour?

### Why I am asking

These questions arise when you try to use undocumented methods. For example to [change the status bar text color in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23387715/754705). Or to [override some undocumented method in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373103/754705) when you have the source, but you don't want to modify it for some reason.

Does my solution A have any effect at runtime? Is it possible somehow to see in the binary that I declared a private category (`MichaelHacksIt`) or does it just silence the compiler? (Note that there is no `@implementation` for this category.)

My main question is: Is it possible to disable the "No visible @interface for 'SomeClass' declares the selector 'fooBar'"?

Comment: You don't have "treat warnings as errors" enabled, do you?

Comment: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245317/why-is-no-known-method-for-selector-x-a-hard-error-under-arc)

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20582863/1187415 is a link to a response from an Apple Developer *why* this was made a "fatal" error with ARC.

Comment: interesting; didn't know that this was a byproduct of ARC

Comment: I thought private APIs were an app store no-no.

Comment: @stevesliva well, partly. if you obfuscate the code enough, they may not find out ;). and: not all apps and libraries are meant for the official app store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message has been introduced together with [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

More information about this particular error message and why it is now a fatal error in ARC can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582863/1187415).

(this is just a summary of the comments below the original question)